# React Native - Open the device default gallery app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-gallery, camera-roll

I'm developing a camera for a React Native app, and it needs to include a button to open the device gallery app (gallery for android, camera roll for iOS). All photos are stored in a specific album, so it would be better to open the app in that album, if possible, but it's not mandatory. It's worth noting that I don't want to create a custom in-app gallery. That would actually be easier, but it's not what the client asked for.

It seems to be a pretty simple task, but I haven't found a way to do this yet. Some people suggested using linking, like this:

```
Linking.openURL('content://media/internal/images/media');
```

This makes the OS ask the user what app should be used to open that link. If I select Google Photos, it works fine. However, if I use the default android gallery, it opens a photo that doesn't exist, showing a placeholder image. So this method doesn't work reliably.

According to android docs, it should be possible to open the gallery app by using an intent. But I tried doing both:

```
Linking.sendIntent('CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY');
Linking.sendIntent('android.intent.category.APP_GALLERY');
```

and it didn't work. Either I'm doing something wrong, or sendIntent doesn't work at all.

There's also a plugin called "react-native-send-intent", but it doesn't include a function to open the gallery. I'm running out of ideas, any help would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my personal project.

According to [the doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?hl=ja#CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY), `CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY` is just specifying app categories and must be used with the `ACTION_MAIN` action.

As far as I understand, we cannot pass a category via React Native built-in `Linking.sendIntent()` method, unfortunately. We must rely on third-party libraries on that part.

I picked up `expo-intent-launcher` (If you are not using expo, still you can use it by following bare workflow as it's described in [the doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/intent-launcher/)).
Here is a working snippet example with `expo-intent-launcher`:

```
import * as IntentLauncher from 'expo-intent-launcher';

IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync('android.intent.action.MAIN', {
          category: 'android.intent.category.APP_GALLERY',
        })
```

Comment: Forgot to note this, `CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY` is just a constant variable name, not a value. You should use `android.intent.category.APP_GALLERY` instead.